# Python RegEx or-ing problems

Tags: python, regex

Hey there I'm just trying to do some simple regEx. What i want is anything in between a ? and a &, or a & and a &, or & and the end of a string. So I've been reading the docks, and I feel, like I should at least be getting close with patters such as:

```
p = re.compile('(\?.*?&)|(&.*?&)|(&.*?$)')
```

or

```
re.compile('[&\?](.*?)&')
```

but all variants I try are a little wonky. An explanation of what you did would also be nice. An Example:

```
?k=091910918&ack=901828312&p=999998
```

and it should yeild:

```
k=091910918, ack=901828312, and p=999998
```

as answers. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[?&]([^?&]+)', '?k=091910918&ack=901828312&p=999998')
['k=091910918', 'ack=901828312', 'p=999998']
```

Regular expression:

```
[?&]           # any character of: '?', '&'
(              # group and capture to \1:
  [^?&]+       #   any character except: '?', '&' (1 or more times)
)              # end of \1
```

You could just split here as well... assuming your string looks like this:

```
>>> filter(None, re.split('[?&]', '?k=091910918&ack=901828312&p=999998'))
['k=091910918', 'ack=901828312', 'p=999998']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind only having one matched group, use this:

```
[\?&](\w+\=\d+)
```

If you want to have two matched groups for each one, use this:

```
[\?&](\w+)\=(\d+)
```

Pretty much the main problem you were having was that you were giving the regex too much flexibility on what to capture by using `.*`.  If you restrict what each group can be a little, it ends up being much more cooperative.

[Here's a demo of the first regex on Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oJ8dB9/1)